# PHPMailer send tag <link> and <script>

Tags: bootstrap-4, phpmailer, html-email

i am trying to send via PHPMailer page that includes Bootstrap CDN.
The page has the following includes:
`<script src=https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js integrity=sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy crossorigin=anonymous></script>`

`<link href=https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`

if i open my page via browser it displays everything correctly but when i send it via PHPMailer it doesn't include bootstrap CDNs and show the simple html without style and js.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `link` and `script` tags aren't supported in email, so this won't work

Comment: Just like @Gwesolo said, HTML emails are supposed to be inline and no JS.